# How to compare two different color images?

Tags: matlab, colors, comparison

I would like to compare two images(RGB images) of same size. How can we compare the color information.
Kindly give your thoughts regarding this...Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? Is it really just the color information, as in accessing the RGB values of a pixel.

Comment: Please tell us more about your requirement. If it is just a pixel then it can be accessed using normal array comparisons otherwise if you want to compare entire image you should use loop to compare every corresponding pixel in to different images.

Comment: I want to compare two images to know whether they are identical or not(Both in color and structure).

Comment: I want to compare the entire RGB image with another RGB image. Can we try histogram matching. If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you state "I want to compare two images to know whether they are identical or not(Both in color and structure)", so you could easily get a yes/no answer with:

```
isequal(I1,I2)
```

Now, if you want more details about the difference (e.g. is it intensity, color, which pixels) you need to specify what.  However, to compare structure regardless of color information (hue and saturation), you can convert each image to grayscale with `rgb2gray` and compare in intensity space.

If you want to know which pixels are different, use `find`:

```
[differentRows, differentCols] = find(I1gray~=I2gray);
```

Maybe you want to compare hue and saturation (again, the color information) without regard to intensity?  Convert each image to HSV with `rgb2hsv` and compare the H and S planes:

```
I1hsv = rgb2hsv(I1); I2hsv = rgb2hsv(I2);
diffH = abs(I1hsv(:,:,1)-I2hsv(:,:,1));
diffS = abs(I1hsv(:,:,2)-I2hsv(:,:,2));
```

There are many ways to compare two images.  Hopefully this helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, if you want to compare the intensity values of two images **I1** and **I2**, you can use [imsubstract](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsubtract.html).

```
imsubtract(I1, I2); %Show if the two intensity images are identical
```

Comment: From that result how can we interpret the color difference between the images?

Comment: What do you mean by the color difference? Can you show the operation with 1 pixel?